# Copy selected cells of information when one cell equals a specific text/word

Tags: excel

Trying to get relevant rows of data into individual tabs based on the cell information in one cell. When a that cell equals specific text it will then copy multiple cells from the one row into the customers tab.

Workbook tabs include
'Data' - contains every customer and information for each transaction
Following tabs for example would be
'SmithP' - Filters the results down to transactions only for customer SmithP
etc

Data Column's
Column 'Data!S:S' contains the customers name example 'SmithP'.
Columns 'Data!I:N' contains the information I need to be copied to the individual tabs that will create for each individual customers name based of the customers.

It could be done by just sorting each row and then copy and pasting the information over but have more than 10,000 rows of transactions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use "Start > Format as table" to get your data into table form. This will make accessing the information in the columns much easier. Then give your table a name, for instance "data".

From now on, you can reference your columns as data[name], data[information1], data[information2], etc., depending on the header of the column.

Now you have 2 ways of going on. Approach 1 is to generate a tab for each user, approach 2 is to generate a dynamic user tab.

**1) Multi tab solution**

In each tab, you need to have the user name written somewhere, let's assume in A1. To speeden up the process, use an invisible formula in A2 to do the following:

`=MATCH(A1,data[name])`

This formula will return the row number of the user in A1. The rest is pretty straightfoward. Use index to get the information you need in the cell you want. For instance if you need information 2, then use:

`=INDEX(data[information1],A2)`

This will retrieve information1 from the same line as the user's name. Just duplicate the tab and change the user name accordingly.

**2) Dynamic tab solution**

If, however, a single tab is enough, you can use a similar solution to 1, but with dynamic updates. First, make a list of all people you need and put it somewhere on your dynamic user tab or in an extra tab made for the list only.

Then use the same formulas as in solution 1.

Now comes the magic. Select cell A1 and go to "Data > Data validation". There, choose list and mark the list of names you just created. Tick the "dropdown" checkbox and click ok. Now you can select a user from the dropdown list in the name field and the other fields will update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it with VBA. 
- use macro recorder to record what you are doing and discover how to create a new sheet:
[image]

- iterate over every items and do the copy / paste work
- you must find a way to remember which customer you stored in which tab. The easiest is to call the tab with the customer name, and have a counter in each tab (row:1/col:20)
- In order to check if the tab was already created, I use below function:

```vba
Function WorksheetExists(sName As String) As Boolean
    WorksheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & sName & "'!A1)")
End Function
```

```vba
Public Sub filterit()
    On Error GoTo ErrorTrap
    Dim wkRange As Range
    Dim cpSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myOffset As Integer
    rem myOffset is -11 -> -6  since I scan col "S" and I get data from col "I" to "N"
    myOffset = -11

    Set wkRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("$S:$S")
    For Each C In wkRange
      If C.Value = "" Then
        Exit Sub
      End If
       ' MsgBox C.Value
       ' create a new tab with customer name:
      If Not WorksheetExists(C.Value) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Set cpSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        cpSheet.Name = C.Value
      End If
      Set cpSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(C.Value)
      ' count how many rows you entered
      cpSheet.Cells(1, 20) = cpSheet.Cells(1, 20) + 1
      ' then you can do the copy, say on 3 consecutive columns, starting at myOffset
      cpSheet.Cells(cpSheet.Cells(1, 20), 1) = C.offset(0, myOffset + 1).Value
      cpSheet.Cells(cpSheet.Cells(1, 20), 2) = C.offset(0, myOffset + 2).Value
      cpSheet.Cells(cpSheet.Cells(1, 20), 3) = C.offset(0, myOffset + 3).Value
      cpSheet.Cells(cpSheet.Cells(1, 20), 4) = C.offset(0, myOffset + 4).Value
      cpSheet.Cells(cpSheet.Cells(1, 20), 5) = C.offset(0, myOffset + 5).Value
    Next

Exit Sub
ErrorTrap:
    Beep
    MsgBox "FAILED" & Chr(13) & "Error number: " & Err & Chr(13) & Error(Err)
End Sub
```